# Adding Chrome/Chromium Extension to Multiple to Multiple User Profiles

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, chromium

I am running alpha builds of Chromium (currently Version 21.0.1173.0 (141668)) on Mac OS X 10.6.8 updated.

I do not mean user profiles associated with OS user accounts.  I specifically mean add the same Chrome/Chromium extensions [to different user profiles running under the same OS user](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) so I can log into different Google Apps instances concurrently.  Is there way separate of doing so repetitivel ad nauseam for each profile?  I have like 10+ on my main work user profile and want to keep them all consisten extension-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, went to Chrome Discussion group and found the answer for non-Windows people who do not have the registry option. Missed that there is a JSON file option.

[Group thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/DFXAVWGcYGA)

[Official docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)

My bad.  Next time Google better.